# Exporting values from a Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple header component I want to send out some values in.Although, it may be a little too simple to warrant a component I am trying to figure out how to export the value out of the component. This is what I have so far.

```
import React from "react";
const welcome = { title: "Welcome"}
export default ()=> (
  <h1 className="App-header">{{welcome.title}}</h1>
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? You want a header component that will display a value that is passed into it?

Comment: should I be passing in the props value into the component? Not the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about React is that it is all about composability: being able to create a base component that given x props will product the appropriate ui based on those props.

If I were to build a header component I would expect I may have many headers in my app and each with its own content.

```
export default (props) => (
  <h1 className="App-header">{props.title}</h1>
)
```

and then when I use it:

```
import Header from 'header';

<Header title="my title" />
```

and then you will be able to have the same base configuration and only have to pass in a title through props to be able to use across your app.

great article from the facebook react guides on composability https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html